# Cross Domain Ajax call to MVC WebApi webservices not including credential cookie

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a SharePoint site hosted at sharepoint.mysite.com which I have set up to authenticate with ThinkTecture Identity Server. I am able to log into this site successfully.

I have a MVC WebApi web service set up at webservice.mysite.com which is also configured to authenticate with ThinkTecture Identity Server.

On one of my sharepoint pages, I make a JQuery AJAX call to WebApi web services. I have set crossDomain to true and withCredentials to true. The OPTIONs preflight request returns successfully, but the cookies are not being passed with the actual request.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://webservice.mysite.com/api/[controller]/[method]",
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                data: {},
                datatype: "json",
                success: getDataSuccess,
                error: getDataError
            });
```

The preflight request receives the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 ISIS
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Expires: -1
Date: Fri, 16 May 2014 13:17:28 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sharepoint.mysite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

The request is then sent with the following headers:

```
GET http://webservice.mysite.com/api/[controller]/[method] HTTP/1.1
Host: sharepoint.mysite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
Origin: http://sharepoint.mysite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://sharepoint.mysite.com/page
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Via: 1.1 ISIS
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
Connection: Proxy-Support
Content-Length: 61
Expires: -1
Date: Fri, 16 May 2014 13:29:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sharepoint.mysite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

How can I have it send the credentials cookie with the request?